# Unexpected Token: ILLEGAL on basic click function, jQuery

Tags: jquery, syntax-error

I'm just doing a very simple click function but I get an error on line 6. Even I remove everything other than the click function - still an error. The object is definitely in the HTML and I have alerted $("p#backButton") to check.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var windowWidth = $(document).width();
    if(windowWidth < 767){
        $("p#backButton").css("display","block");
        $("p#backButton a").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            history.back();
            return false;
        });
     }
});
```

Comment: You probably wrote this in JSFiddle and then copy & pasted, right?

Comment: View your code in chrome inspector tools and you'll see your illegal character anyway

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle that has the same issue?

Comment: I realised that other parts in the code were trying to target html elements that weren't on the page. These didn't cause an error but I wonder if it caused the above script to error - even though it was unconnected. In the end I solved this by putting inline javascript on the <a>. I didn't want to do this but was the only way I could find to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue stems from using `history.back()` which in that scope may be undefined. Try using `window.history.back()`

Also try spacing out your code a little bit

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var windowWidth = $(document).width();
    if ( windowWidth < 767 ) {
        $("p#backButton").css("display","block");
        $("p#backButton a").click( function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            window.history.back();
            return false;
        });
     }
});
```

Good luck. Let me know what happens

Comment: If `history` is undefined, then `window.history` will also be undefined.

Answer (score 0):

adding:

```
<a href="#back" onclick="history.back(); return false;" title="Go Back">Back</a>
```

As inline javascript was a work around for this issue - not a desirable fix but was the only way I found to fix it.